# Oracle Regular Expression - Remove space between alphabetic tokens of length 1 within a string

Tags: regex, oracle, oracle11g, regexp-replace

Oracle Version : 11.2

I am new to use of regular expressions and needed some help with coming up with the right REGEXP_REPLACE for our requirement explained below.

Requirement: Remove space between alphabetic tokens of length 1 within a string.

Example 1:

```
"The I B M Corporation N Y US"
```

...should get converted to:

```
"The IBM Corporation NY US"
```

Example 2:

```
"The P N CD FUND of J P R M"
```

...should get converted to:

```
"The PN CD FUND of JPRM"
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for your examples:

```
SELECT regexp_replace('The I B M Corporation N Y US', '([[:alpha:]]{2} [[:alpha:]]{1,1}) | ([[:alpha:]]{1,1})( [[:alpha:]]{2})| ([[:alpha:]]{1,1}$)| ([[:alpha:]]{1,1}) ', '\1\2\3\4\5') as eg_1,
       regexp_replace('The P N CD FUND of J P R M', '([[:alpha:]]{2} [[:alpha:]]{1,1}) | ([[:alpha:]]{1,1})( [[:alpha:]]{2})| ([[:alpha:]]{1,1}$)| ([[:alpha:]]{1,1}) ', '\1\2\3\4\5') as eg_2
  FROM dual;
```

I used this page to help: [regexp_replace](http://www.java2s.com/Book/Oracle/String_Functions/REGEXP_REPLACE_function.htm)

I hope it helps you out!

Answer (score 0):

Sadly I do not know syntax of Oracle regex, but if you have capability of translate regex to another then this one do what you want if used with Regex.Replace() method function in C#

```
(?<=\s\w)\s(?!\w{2,})
```